# Как привязать autonumeric ко всем элементам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу разобраться, autoNumeric работает только на первый элемент содержащий класс `float`, как сделать что бы сработало на всех элементах имеющих класс `float`?

```html
<script src = "https://unpkg.com/autonumeric" ></script>

<form>   
  <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="26" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(26).Answer" />
<br />
  <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="27" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(27).Answer" /> 
 <br /> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control cell-in-text float" id="28" asp-for="@Model.ListEtpAnswer.ElementAt(28).Answer" /> 
 <br /> 
 

<script>
  const autoNumericOptions = {
    allowDecimalPadding: "floats",
    decimalCharacter: ",",
    digitGroupSeparator: "",
    //emptyInputBehavior: "zero",
    watchExternalChanges: true
  };
new AutoNumeric(".float", autoNumericOptions); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации `autoNumeric` написано, что при вызове через конструктор используется `document.querySelector`, т.е. берется только первый элемент из селектора.

Если вам нужны все элементы из селектора то стоит использовать `AutoNumeric.multiple`, т.к. здесь используется `document.querySelectorAll`

```js
const autoNumericOptions = {
  allowDecimalPadding: 'floats',
  decimalCharacter: ',',
  digitGroupSeparator: '',
  watchExternalChanges: true
};
AutoNumeric.multiple('.float', autoNumericOptions);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/autonumeric@4.5.4/dist/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="float" />
  <input class="float" />
  <input class="float" />
  <input class="float" />
</form>
```